# Unsure how to type fractional equations with exponents

Tags: scheme, fractions, exponent

New to programming and have a question regarding defining an equation that is a fraction and has exponents.

This is the question:

Define a function tanh which, given a positive number x , returns the hyperbolic tangent of
x defined as
tanh(x ) = (e^2x − 1)/(e^2x + 1)

You may use the built in SCHEME function (expt b e) function to complete this problem.
(expt b e) computes b^e

I understand that (expt b e) is how you write exponents, but I don't understand how to write "e^x".

Answer (score 0):

`expt` is the power function, whereas `exp` is the natural exponential function.

`(exp x)` gives you e<sup>x</sup>.